# Are peas countable or non-countable?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

Frequently in my childhood a conversation would arise at the dinner table that went something like this;
"How many peas would you like?"
"About sixty please".
(Laughter ensues).

The question befits a countable noun such as sausages. However the correct answer is something which befits a non-countable noun such as rice. "Quite a lot", "Not very much", "A spoonful" or "Less" (rather than "Fewer").
Why is it that peas defy classification as countable or non-countable?

I've had it explained to me that the etymology of pea is a back-engineered (and originally incorrect) singular derived from "pease" which would suggest "How much peas would you like?"  is a grammatically correct question.

However this doesn't explain why the same problem occurs with other small items such as sliced carrots or cornflakes.

Is it size-related? Is there a no-man's land between rice and sausages where English is simply lacking an appropriate solution?

Comment: I don't think the hilarity is related to countability. It's about practicality. No-one would expect someone to count out the peas they're giving someone.

Comment: One could always ask *"how many **spoonfuls** of peas would you like"*, and avoid offering a straight line.

Comment: Are you perhaps being influenced by the singular noun ***pease***, for which OED's definition 2a is *an individual seed of the pea plant, **Pisum sativum;** a pea.* In the etymology for this entry OED says *By late Middle English the plural form was often identical with the singular... After the mid 17th cent. the plural (and collective) form **peas** becomes indistinguishable from the plural of **pea***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers _early or mid-17c., false singular from Middle English pease (plural pesen), which was both single and collective (as with wheat, corn) but the "s" sound was mistaken for the plural inflection. From Old English pise (West Saxon), piose (Mercian) "pea," from Late Latin pisa, variant of Latin pisum "pea," from Greek pison "the pea," perhaps of Thracian or Phrygian origin [Klein]._, from Etymonline.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - You and Peter are two peas in a pod!

Comment: @HotLicks: I wish! Years ago I did actually manage to code my own "quicksort" function after studying the basic logic. But despite several attempts, I don't really even *understand* Peter's quantum computing algorithm. All I know is a lot of people who *do* think that if he hadn't come up with it, development of real-world quantum computers probably wouldn't be where it is today. And on top of that, I'm sure he's got a better ear for language than me! :(

Comment: 'Are peas countable?' is an unhelpful phrasing. The referent is peas, those little green things, which are etically countable (if one wants to be bothered one can count them) until blended, as in mushy peas or pea soup after blending. One, two, three ... 427. // However, the noun 'peas' may occur as the plural count usage (I've dropped 3 peas on the floor) or as the plural-form plural-verb-form-taking non-count usage (We had peas, cabbage and mash with the beef). No matter whether the peas were countable on the plate or not. It's usually possible to avoid ...

Comment: agreement awkwardness ("Have you enough peas?" "Would you like more peas?"), but "Can I have less/fewer peas next time, please?" forces a choice between non-count-quantifier and count-quantifier (I'd go with 'less' here. Though the choice with 'potatoes', usually very obviously etically countable, is even trickier. But there's always "That's one less problem" to cite.)

Answer (score 5):

The *question* may be "How many peas?" (countable) but the *answer* is expressed by quantity not count (ie, "A spoonful," as if a mass noun).

Presumably this is because although the items are **theoretically** countable like apples, they are **practically** uncountable, like sand.

Comment: Even if practically countable, it was not meant for them to be counted anyway. :)

Comment: So I suppose the answer is that the questioner is incorrect for treating them as countable in the first place. Not often that mum is wrong! :)

Comment: @rickyzenon: If they were uncountable, you would have to ask "how much peas would you like," which isn't proper English.

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside the question of etymology, today, *pea* is an English word (countable, pl. *peas;* also *peas* uncountable/mass noun.)

In a context where the reference is to an individual 'spherical green seed which is eaten as a vegetable *Pisum sativum,* ' ([ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pea)) it is the countable noun.

Where the reference is to the bulk, use the mass noun *peas.*

> Stop throwing **peas** at the girl!  (plural of countable)
>
> Another helping of **peas**, guest?  (uncountable)

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back up the claim that *peas* can be an uncountable noun?

Comment: There's an example in the answer. *Pea(s)* is not an exceptional case, there may be many other such.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. I read that as the the plural of *pea*.

Comment: No, *peas* in the second case refers to a dish (mass) made of peas (countable). HTH. *I closed my eyes tightly and sent out a wish\ That the peas would somehow disappear from my dish.* ()

Comment: It still seems to me like you're over-complicating things. I guess what would help would be some kind of reference. You've provided one for the countable noun and there's nothing *there* to suggest to me that your second sentence requires a different interpretation of the word.

Comment: If your last sentence is clearly an uncountable use of *peas*, than [pickles](http://books.google.com/books?id=infVKufj5BsC&pg=PA29&dq=%22Ethan+reached+over+for+another+helping+of+pickles%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qJPXU57pEM2YyAT-p4HAAg&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Ethan%20reached%20over%20for%20another%20helping%20of%20pickles%22&f=false) and [potatoes](http://books.google.com/books?id=7OhNkGB5PtUC&pg=PA87&dq=%22another+helping+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_5PXU8abMIyVyATi-oL4DA&ved=0CEwQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22another%20helping%20of%22&f=false) are also uncountable nouns.

Comment: When it's mass, it's pronounced the same as _peas_, but it's spelled _pease_. That was the original term, from Latin _pisum_. It's cooked dried peas; what we call _split-pea soup_ in the US. We also all know the children's rhyme: _Pease porridge hot, pease porridge cold, pease porridge in the pot nine days old. Some like it hot, some like it cold, some like it in the pot, nine days old._  Count noun _pea_ was back-formed from _pease_ when peas began to be eaten green and shelled as a vegetable and the need arose for a singular. Now it's standard.

Comment: For comparison, try _rice_. Or _bean_. Or _oats_. Or Mexican Spanish, where _frijoles_ are individual beans, while _frijol_ is the refried bean dish.

Answer (score 0):

*Microsoft® Encarta® 2009* contrasts the following

> ***peas* (plural noun) [U.S. FOOD]:** the unopened immature pods of the pea,
>   containing the seeds and used as a vegetable
>
> ***pea* (plural *peas*)** 
>   1. a round green seed that grows in a pod, eaten as a vegetable 
>   2. an annual vine of the legume family with compound leaves that is widely grown for its edible seeds. Latin name: Pisum sativum

Cambridge Grammar of the English Language

> Larger entities such as *peas, strawberries*, and *potatoes* are
>   individuated and lexicalised as count nouns (*mashed potato* is a
>   homogeneous substance prepared from potatoes). When *peas*,
>   *strawberries*, and *potatoes* are gathered together, we simply pluralise
>   the count noun: *peas*.

Comment: In the first heading, a _plural noun_ is "(grammar): A noun that inherently refers to multiple items" (Wiktionary)